# Can insert records without a matching key in the referencing table

Tags: sqlite, coronasdk

This is how I create my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS providences ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE, country_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY( country_id ) REFERENCES countries( id ) )
```

The tables are created without any errors.

Now I need to insert a country, it gets assigned ID 1

```
INSERT INTO countries( name ) VALUES('sweden')
```

Now I want to insert a couple of providences to my country as well:

```
INSERT INTO providences( name, country_id ) VALUES('Lappland', 1 )
INSERT INTO providences( name, country_id ) VALUES('Norrbotten', 2 ) <-- Oops! Non-existing country_id!
```

Both providences gets inserted but I was expecting that only the providence with country_id = 1 should be inserted as there is no country with id 2 in the database.

Am I missing something here?

This SQL that I am using in Corona SDK.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me.  You need to pass in the country_id as a value.  So the province has an id of 1 and 2 respectively, and Sweden has an country_id of one.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS providences ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, country_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY( country_id ) REFERENCES countries( id ) );

INSERT INTO countries(id ,name ) VALUES(1,'sweden');
INSERT INTO providences( id, name, country_id ) VALUES(1,'Lappland', 1 );
INSERT INTO providences( id, name, country_id ) VALUES(2, 'Norrbotten', 1 );
```

Comment: My code works as well but I _don't_ want it to work due to the Foreign Key Constraint.